# Testing the output of an Observable

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, rxjs-observables

Having difficulty wrapping my head around observables. I have the following:

```
const check = this.http.get(myUrl);
```

This returns JSON data. I want to test that the "url" field exists in the JSON data. If it doesn't I'd like to query a second URL. (Assume the API is fixed and two calls are necessary, because that is in fact the case.)

The problem is that I can't figure out how to do that. If `check` was just JSON (and no an observable) this would be trivial:

```
if(check.url) {
    return check;
} else {
    return this.http.get(myOtherUrl);
}
```

This clearly doesn't work as I can't directly check the URL property. Reading the page on [RxJS operators](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#operators), I've written the following:

```
const check = this.http.get(myUrl);
const mapResponse = map(response => {
    ...format data into JSON structure...
    return jsonResponse;
});
mapResponse(check).subscribe(result => {
  if (result['url']) {
      return result;
  } else {
      return this.http.get(myOtherUrl);
  }
});
```

This looks crazy awkward, as in order to use the second `get` I'd have to replicate the code within the lambda function. Not sure how to access the result of the second `http` call to actually do something with it. Should I just nest the entire thing again?

Comment: As I was posting I noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49926634/168775), but wasn't sure if that was the answer I'm looking for here.

Comment: What do you think returning a value from a subscribe callback do?

Comment: I apologize, the return shouldn't be there. Edited.

Comment: You need to subscribe to the `this.http.get(myOtherUrl)` observable, yes nested inside, I'm not sure why you don't want to do that

Comment: You need to chain your calls, I don't know the exact syntax but something along the lines of `this.http.get(myUrl).pipe(flatMap(response) => response.url ? response : this.http.get(myOtherUrl);)` That should return an observable for the first or second request depending on whether the  first call had a `url` property. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104638/how-to-chain-http-calls-in-angular2

Comment: Also consider [converting the observables to Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52497250/227299), it would make it more readable if you're not an rx-js expert.